# Flutter page routes

Tags: flutter, routes

I want to navigate from home page to login page. I have implemented some code. But it is not work. There is an error when running the code. MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => LoginPage())); this line occurs the error. I can not resolve this whether I have tried so many times. Here is the full code segment.

```
return Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text("Home"),
        backgroundColor: Colors.grey[500],
        actions: <Widget>[
            PopupMenuButton<String>(
              child: Container(
                width: 63,
                height: 63,
                child: alucard,
              ),
              onSelected: (value) {
                if(value == Constants.logout){
                  Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => LoginPage()));
                }
              },
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context) {
                return Constants.choices.map((String choice){
                  return PopupMenuItem<String>(

                    value: choice,
                    child: Text(choice),
                  );
                }).toList();
              },
            )
        ],
      ),
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey[800],
      body: body,
      drawer: AppDrawer(value:this.value),
    );
```

This is the error occurred.

```
{
    "resource": "/d:/3rd Year/Group Project II/CrickDom/SLCricketLeaderBoad_MoblieApp/crick_dom/lib/home.dart",
    "owner": "dart",
    "code": {
        "value": "argument_type_not_assignable",
        "target": {
            "$mid": 1,
            "external": "https://dart.dev/tools/diagnostic-messages#argument_type_not_assignable",
            "path": "/tools/diagnostic-messages",
            "scheme": "https",
            "authority": "dart.dev",
            "fragment": "argument_type_not_assignable"
        }
    },
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "The argument type 'MaterialPageRoute<dynamic>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'.",
    "source": "dart",
    "startLineNumber": 84,
    "startColumn": 21,
    "endLineNumber": 84,
    "endColumn": 73,
    "tags": []
}
```

This my Flutter doctor result.

```
 Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.17.3, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18362.900], locale en-US)

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 28.0.3)
[√] Android Studio (version 3.6)
[√] VS Code (version 1.46.1)
[√] Connected device (1 available)

• No issues found!
```

Could anyone can help me to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `Navigator.pushReplacementNamed` use `Navigator.pushReplacement`.

The problem is that `Navigator.pushReplacementNamed` is used to navigate to a named route and accepts a `String` as its second parameter, but you are passing a `MaterialPageRoute` instead which causes an error.

To learn more about named routes you can take a look at this [tutorial](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/named-routes).